# issue in synchronized function execution in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to sync three functions which have AJAX calls in them.

```
main(){
compileTemplate();
}

compileTemplate(){
func1();
func2();
func3();
}

each func has structure like :

func(){
$.when($.get(url)).then(func(d)
{//do something});
```

Each func() is completing on its own. i need when func1 completes then func2 should start.

checked

```
 $.when(func1()).then(func2());
```

but its not working. please do anyone has any idea.

Comment: you want to use function reference, not returned value (if any): `.then(func2);`  FYI, chaining `.then()` has not expected behaviour in jq<1.8

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the return value of `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are promises:

```
function func1() {
    var d = new $.Deffered();
    setTimeout(function () {
        d.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    return d.promise();
}
function func2() {
    return $.ajax(/* .. */);
}
function func3() {
    return /* etc */
}
```

Then you can:

```
$.when(func1()).then(func2).then(func3); // notice the () or lack thereof
```

Or:

```
$.when(func1()).then(function () {
    return func2();
}).then(function () {
    return func3();
});
```

If you don't know whether `func1`, `func2` and `func3` will always return a promise this will still work, but you can not wait for it.

---

If you do:

```
$.when(func1()).then(func2()).then(func3());
```

`func1`, `func2` add `func3` will be called immediately, rather than serially. This is equvalent to:

```
var a = func1();
var b = func2();
var c = func3();
$.when(a).then(b).then(c);
//or
$.when(a, b, c);
```

Comment: That makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
function func1() {
  if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200) {
  ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = func2;
  ajaxObject.send();
  }
}

function func2() {
  if (ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200) {
  ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = func3;
  ajaxObject.send();
}

function func3() {
}
```

Comment: This creates a coupling between func1, func2 and func3 that is not present in OPs sample.